# Pre-populate Fields in webform Drupal 9

Tags: drupal-webform, drupal-9

Is it possible to pre-populate a drupal9 webform with values from the database?
I have two webforms. Customers and Service Report. The customer information will be filled in from the office and the service tech has to fill in the service report on site.

Every saved Customer has an automatically generated Submission ID.
on the Service Report i would like to enter the Submission ID from the Customer to per-populate the same existing fields automatically (Name,Company,Adress etc..)

is this possible? any help is apericated

[Id Lock up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTcZP.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

How should the Submission ID be integrated in der ServiceReport? What is the Userstory?

for ex. you can set an Entity-field in ServiceReport (for ex Dropdown) which shows all the customers. The user can select one customer. So there is a connection with the id between two tables.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did created a Entity reverence view from the customer and placed a entity-field in the service report. this lookup is working fine. what i don't understand is how can i pre-populate the rest of the customer information in the Service Report Webform, like street post code city and so on i edited my post and added a picture what i would like to archive